# Google Drive API Upload file failed using Google Drive SDK in .NET

Tags: .net, uwp, google-drive-api

I try to upload an audio file to google drive. This is my source code:

```
   public override async void UploadLocalFileToDrive(StorageFile localFile, string driveFolderName)
    {
        if (localFile != null)
        {
            string folderId = await GetFolderIdByNameAsync(driveFolderName);
            if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(folderId))
            {
                var uploadFile = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File();
                uploadFile.Name = localFile.Name;
                uploadFile.Parents = new List<string>() { folderId };
                uploadFile.MimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.audio";

                Stream stream = await localFile.OpenStreamForReadAsync();

                try
                {
                    var request = driveService.Files.Create(uploadFile, stream, uploadFile.MimeType);
                    await request.UploadAsync();
                    Debug.WriteLine(request.ResponseBody.Id);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

When this function is called, no file is uploaded to drive and object

```
 request.ResponseBody
```

is null.

I'm using Google.Apis.Drive.v3 library for UWP .Net

How can I fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Could you post the code for the user authentication? Or have you not done this yet

Comment: Because UWP doesn't suppoert fully Google.Apis.Drive.v3 library, my code for the user authentication so long. I have an user authentication before, so i can get folder id by GetFolderIdByNameAsync function. Scopes of user authentication is https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive

Comment: It looks pretty supported on the [official docs](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/dotnet), although I haven't had the chance to use it myself.  So the GetFolderIdByNameAsync() call returns a successful value?

Comment: Yes. The result is a successful value. And I could fix this mistake by change file's MimeType to `audio/mpeg`. I wrote it in my answer below. Thanks for interested in my question.

Answer (score 0):

I found a mistake in my code. It's I use `appliction/vnd.gooogle-apps.audio` for MimeType of file. It must be `audio/mpeg`. Thanks for interested in!